# JBoss7: loader constraint violation with ReastEasy and httpclient with custom HttpRequestInterceptor

Tags: java, classloader, jboss7.x, resteasy

I'm using the RestEasy Client Framework in a `@Named @ViewScoped` Bean with JBoss-7.1.1-Final to retrieve data from a REST service with a custom `HttpRequestInterceptor`:

```
RegisterBuiltin.register(ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance());

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.addRequestInterceptor(new PreemptiveAuthInterceptor("test","test"), 0);

ClientExecutor clientExecutor = new ApacheHttpClient4Executor(httpClient); //<---

//The error occurs above, the code below is only for completeness
MyRest rest = ProxyFactory.create(MyRest.class,
                                    "http://localhost:8080/rest",clientExecutor);
```

This works fine in a standalone client application (also ok when I remove the `ClientExecutor`, but I need it to authenticate REST service). The bean is in a `WAR` module inside an `EAR`, the dependency hierarchy of resteasy resolves to the following:

[image: Resteasy dependency]

There are no `httpclient` or `httpcore` in the `WAR` or `EAR`. Inside the Bean I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/HttpRequestInterceptor
```

Seems to be easy (although I'm wondering about the resteasy packaging) and I added `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` with *compile* scope:

[image]

No I'm getting he following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method   
  "org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>    
  (Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;)V"
  the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader)
      of the current class, my/TestBean, and
  the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader)
      for resolved class, 
  org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/executors/ApacheHttpClient4Executor,
  have different Class objects for the type org/apache/http/client/HttpClient
  used in the signature my.TestBean.init(TestBean.java:65)
```

**Update** To reproduce this you don't need REST interfaces, the error occurs while instantiating the `ApacheHttpClient4Executor`, but you may need the custom `PreemptiveAuthInterceptor`:

```
public class PreemptiveAuthInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor
{
  private String username;
  private String password;

  public PreemptiveAuthInterceptor(String username, String password)
  {
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
  }

  @Override
  public void process(org.apache.http.HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException
  {
    AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(ClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);

    authState.setAuthScope(org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope.ANY);
    authState.setCredentials(new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username,password));
    authState.setAuthScheme(new BasicScheme());

  }
}
```

Comment: This has been a bug for a while: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2803

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To avoid the linkage error when *deploying* the application on JBoss, configure module `org.apache.httpcomponents` within the modules folder of the JBoss installation, but avoid including the JARs from HttpComponents with your application:

1. Place the required JARs from HttpComponents in `modules/org/apache/httpcomponents/main`.
2. List these JARs in `module.xml` within this directory.
3. Add `Dependencies: org.apache.httpcomponents` to the `MANIFEST.MF` of your component.

Note that the module referred to in step 1 and 2 already exists. You may however want to include additional JARS (e.g. `httpclient-cache-x.y.z.jar`) or different versions.

Resolving classes within your *development environment* is another matter of course.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in similar circumstances. The HttpComponents module required was already in my JBoss (AS 7.1.1) modules directory. Therefore, all I had to do to resolve the issue was to add a manifest entry as described by Eustachius, which in Maven you can do like so:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>org.apache.httpcomponents</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The configuration is the same for the maven-war-plugin.

Answer (score 2):

If a module is needed in an Arquillian test...

Create arquillian-manifest.mf in src/test/resources with the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Dependencies: org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs,org.apache.httpcomponents
```

Then when you ShrinkWrap:

```
WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create...
    .addAsManifestResource("arquillian-manifest.mf", "MANIFEST.MF")
```

Answer (score 0):

But Add Dependencies: org.apache.httpcomponents to the MANIFEST.MF of your component.

causing an exception -
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS014744: No META-INF/services/org.jboss.as.controller.Extension found for org.apache.httpcomponents:main
    at org.jboss.as.controller.parsing.ExtensionXml.loadModule(ExtensionXml.java:191) [jboss-as-controller-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]